# Allow a model instance to be added to the moderation queue based on a condition using Django-Moderation

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

Given a model as :

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)#Title of the Post
    body = models.TextField(blank=False)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=60,choices=STATE_CHOICES,default='raw')`
```

A blog instance is added to Django-Moderation's moderation queue only if `state=published`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem is to use the "Automoderation" feature of Django-Moderation. Whenever we save our model instance using `instance.save()` we automoderate the model instance by over-riding the `is_auto_approve()` function of `Generic Moderator` as shown.

```
class BlogModerator(GenericModerator):

def is_auto_approve(self, obj, user):
    if obj.state == "raw":
        return self.reason('Not Submitted Yet !')
    super(MyModelModerator, self).is_auto_approve(obj, user)
```

Here all instances in which `state = raw` bypass moderation or else are added to the moderation queue.